# Не отображается гугл капча

Tags: recaptcha

Перехожу на новый дизайн сайта, и вот при переносе всей начинки, перестала отображаться гугл капча, если смотреть через имеющиеся элементы на страницы, то там она прописана, но её не видно.
В чем может быть проблема?

На странице капча интегрирована следующим образом:

на самой странице регистрации блок:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" data-callback="mySuperFunction"></div> 


function mySuperFunction(captchaKey){
    capkeygoogle = captchaKey;
}
```

В файле-обработчике Registration.php:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$key = '';
$query = $url.'?secret='.$key.'&response='.$_POST['capkeygoogle'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));

if ( $data->success == false)   {

    $message = 'Kapcha not introduced!';
    $color = 'red';
    $out = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'color' => $color
    );

    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($out);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Вариантов куча, надо смотреть конкретно. Приведите пример кода, как вы работаете с каптчей.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev обновил вопрос